# clGetDeviceInfo and clGetPlatformInfo fails in OpenCL with error code -30 (CL_INVALID_VALUE)

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu, opencl.net

I am starting to write a little "engine" for using OpenCL. Now, I encountered a problem that is quite strange.

When I call `clGetDeviceInfo()` to query informations of the specific device, some of the options for the parameter `param_name` return the error code -30 ( = CL_INVALID_VALUE). A very famous one is the option CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS which should return me a string of extensions no matter what sdk or platform I am using. I checked every edge and also the parameters are double checked.

Another thing I do not understand is when I run my source on my Windows machine at work, the `clGetPlatformInfo()` function also returns me CL_INVALID_VALUE querying the CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS string. At home I am using a Linux machine running Ubuntu and it shows the extensions string without any problem.

---

Here are the data of my platforms:

- Work:

  - Intel Core i5 2500 CPU
  - NVIDIA Geforce 210 GPU
  - AMD APP SDK 3.0 Beta
- Home:

  - Intel Core i7 5820K CPU
  - AMD Radeon HD7700 GPU
  - AMD APP SDK 3.0 Beta

---

And here is the source:

The source is written in cpp and the opencl fuctions are embedded in some wrapper classes (i.e. OCLDevice).

```
OCLDevice::OCLDevice(cl_device_id device)
{
  cl_int errNum;
  cl_uint uintBuffer;
  cl_long longBuffer;
  cl_bool boolBuffer;   
  char str[128];
  size_t strSize = (sizeof(char) * 128);
  size_t retSize;

  //Device name string.
  errNum = 
      clGetDeviceInfo(device,CL_DEVICE_NAME,strSize,(void*)str,&retSize);
  throwException();
  this->name = string(str,retSize);

  //The platform associated with this device.
  errNum = 
     clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_PLATFORM,
                     sizeof(cl_platform_id),
                     (void*)&(this->platform), &retSize);
  throwException();

  //The OpenCL device type.
  errNum = 
      clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_TYPE, 
                      sizeof(cl_device_type),
                      (void*)&(this->devType),&retSize);
  throwException();

  //Vendor name string.
  errNum = 
      clGetDeviceInfo(device,CL_DEVICE_VENDOR,
                      strSize,(void*)str,&retSize);
  throwException();
  this->vendor = string(str,retSize);

  //A unique device vendor identifier. 
  //An example of a unique device identifier could be the PCIe ID.
  errNum =
      clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID,
                      sizeof(unsigned int),
                      (void*)&(this->vendorID),&retSize);
  throwException();

  //Returns a space separated list of extension names
  //supported by the device.
  clearString(str,retSize); //fills the char string with 0-characters
  errNum =
      clGetDeviceInfo(device,CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS,strSize,str,&retSize);
  throwException();

  //some more queries (some with some without the same error)...
}
```

---

As you can see in the code *param_value_size* > *param_value_size_ret* so that there is no reason to return the error, too. The *param_name* is copied from the header to be save there is no typing error.

It would be great if somebody knew an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenCL specification states that `clGetDeviceInfo` can return `CL_INVALID_VALUE` if (among other things):

> ... or if size in bytes specified by *param_value_size* is < size of return type as specified in *table 4.3* ...

For the `CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS` query, you have allocated storage for 128 characters, and are passing 128 as the `param_value_size` parameter. If the device supports a lot of extensions, it is entirely possible that it needs *more* than 128 characters.

You can query the amount of space needed to store the query result by passing `0` and `NULL` to the `param_value_size` and `param_value` arguments, and then use this to allocate sufficient storage:

```
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, 0, NULL, &retSize);

char extensions[retSize];
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, retSize, extensions, &retSize);
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, that solved my problem. I do it now the malloc way and everything is working well.